# Can't add C# class to Web API Project - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, webapi

I have a solution that includes a ASP.NET Core Web Api project. When i try to add a new class inside the Controller folder or any other, i don't have the C# Class item to add. The only thing with a c# in the list is an Assembly Informatino File.

In any other non-webAPI project this does not happend.

[image]

Comment: You can add a class by just typed ClassName.cs in the Name and press Add

Comment: Can you right click on the `controllers` folder > add > class...?  Where `class` should be an option in the right click menu.

Answer (score -1):

Please, Navigate into the Visual Studio installer.

Click the Modify Button.

check ASP.NET and Web Development and then install. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can add the class by right click on the `controllers` folder and choose `Add>>>Class>>>Enterclassname`.

[image]

Comment: No, you can't. Obviously the OP knows how to find the context menu, otherwise he wouldn't have posted the screenshot. The problem is that the normal C# file options won't show up in the dialog, only the strange list of JavaScript and TypeScript files.